# For Loop to count duplicate values in each variable of a matrix

Tags: r, loops, counting

I have this code so far.  I'm trying to see how many variables contain a duplicate letter in them.  For example, in variable 1 if I have {a, b, c, c, d} I would want this to return as true.  Haven't done for loops in R ever.  Any help?

```
wordSoup<-replicate(100,(replicate(5,sample(letters,1))))
notUnique=0

for (i in wordSoup) {
  if (anyDuplicated(wordSoup[,i])==1) {
  notUnique=notUnique+1
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you searched here yet for questions related to loops, duplicates, and R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option without the for loop. It will return a logical vector with the same length of the column numbers. `TRUE` means there are duplicates, while `FALSE` means all letters are unique in that column.

```
apply(wordSoup, 2, function(x) any(table(x) > 1))
```

Another idea is using `unique` to get the unique letters and then use `length` to see the number of unique letters. If it is smaller than 5, then it means there are duplicates and returns `TRUE`.

```
apply(wordSoup, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)) < 5)
```

Comment: Thank you!  That definitely works.  I'll be researching the apply function I suppose.

Comment: @Austin I am glad to help. I just updated the post with another approach, but it still uses `apply`. function.

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes more intuitive sense to me.  I'll go with that.  Both meet the intent, though.